# I need to combine two separate number ranges in one enquiry (my enquiry also does not function)

Tags: lua

I am struggling to get my lua script to execute properly due to this section of the script.

First, let me explain what the conditions are and then I'll share what I have tried, that isn't working for me.

I have two objects affixed as children to a 3d model and am scripting conditions for when one should be visible and the other should be hidden. The objects are called ETH1 and ETH2. The number range for ETH1 to show is between 47401-47420 and 47473-47599. The number range ETH2 to show is 47421-47472.

Now to my script. The 5 digit numbers are expressed as variable vehicleNumber as it forms the start of an 11 character string.

```
convertedNum = tonumber(vehicleNumber);
     if convertedNum >= 47401 and convertedNum <= 47420 then
          ETH1 = true
          ETH2 = false
     elseif convertedNum >= 47473 and convertedNum <= 47599 then
          ETH1 = true
          ETH2 = false
     else
          ETH1 = false
          ETH2 = true
 end
```

The vehicleNumber variable wokrs fine as it is functioning elsewhere within the script and utilises the string as required.

Thanks very much, I've spent many hours pulling my hair out at this as I get no lua debugging in the software this is for, I just know it's broken because other items are non-functional.

Comment: please read [ask]. Your post doesn't make too much sense. you pasted some code  that does something but it's not clear what is wrong about it. what do you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: You can "combine" two boolean expressions with `or`, for example: `if a >= 1 and a <= 3 or a >= 7 and a <= 9 then ... end`

Comment: Thanks both for your responses and apologies that I haven't done a good job of posting. -  Piglet, all of the child objects show on the parent object AND all of the previous scripted controls and workings no longer function, whereas they did before the inclusion of the section of code above. Egor - I shall try that ASAP but it looks like that may be waiting I'm looking for and I thank you.